# can't download weblogic plugin for eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin

When Im trying to download weblogic adapter from eclipse, I got this error:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Oracle WebLogic Server Tools 1.7.3.201107052022 (oracle.eclipse.tools.helios.weblogic.feature.group 1.7.3.201107052022)
  Software currently installed: Oracle WebLogic Server Tools 1.7.2.201103302044 (oracle.eclipse.tools.helios.weblogic.feature.group 1.7.2.201103302044)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Oracle Apache XMLBeans Tools 3.2.2.201103302044 (oracle.eclipse.tools.xmlbeans 3.2.2.201103302044)
    Oracle Apache XMLBeans Tools 3.2.3.201107052022 (oracle.eclipse.tools.xmlbeans 3.2.3.201107052022)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Oracle WebLogic Server Tools 1.7.2.201103302044 (oracle.eclipse.tools.helios.weblogic.feature.group 1.7.2.201103302044)
    To: oracle.eclipse.tools.xmlbeans [3.2.2.201103302044]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Oracle WebLogic Server Tools 1.7.3.201107052022 (oracle.eclipse.tools.helios.weblogic.feature.group 1.7.3.201107052022)
    To: oracle.eclipse.tools.xmlbeans [3.2.3.201107052022]
```

Anyone knows how to solve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this. You need to get the latest build of eclipse, and try. That should fix the problem.